# Make sure that 'gem install nokogiri '1.6.7.2' ' succeeds before bundling. What is going wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, nokogiri

I have created a new app file and when I **'bundle install'** I keep getting the message above. I also don't have a gemfile.lock file.

- Ruby is updated to version 2.3
- I am running this on Windows 8

I have tried  `gem install nokogiri '1.6.7.2'` as well as `gem install nokogiri '1.6.8.rc2'`

I don't understand what could be the problem, please help! :)

Comment: The message means that bundler could not build the native extension of nokogiri, what that means is that source code (usually in C/C++) that is necessary for the gem to work could not be compiled. nokogiri probably failed installing when bundler tried to look for `libxml2` or some other library.
How did you installed rails?

Comment: I installed rails from rubyinstaller, I'm following "Ruby on Rails 4 Essential Training" on lynda.com. I'm not sure if this is relevant at all, but I am trying to set this up with MySQL.

Comment: I'm sure this is not what you are looking for right now but, have you considered installing linux on a virtual machine and do your tutorials there? You really really going to have a hard time with these kind of issues on windows for sure, particularly, with ruby development.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the Windows-specific build of Nokogiri:

http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#windows

Comment: Okay I've got it downloaded but where do I put it? I'm new to rails completely so this really confusing for me

Comment: Navigate to the same folder where you saved the `.gem` file and run `gem install nokogiri` or `gem install --local path_to_gem/filename.gem`

Comment: Gem::InstallError: nokogiri requires Ruby version < 2.3, >= 1.9.2.
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using mime-types 3.0
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using uglifier 3.0.0
Using sprockets 3.6.0
Using sdoc 0.4.1
Using activesupport 4.2.6
Using tzinfo-data 1.2016.4
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.7.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.7.2'` succeeds before bundling.  Okay so the nokogiri installer you helped me with did install but I still can't get passed this which is the ultimate issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem posted from anon on another website.

A quick workaround is the following (ruby 2.3 win64):

```
gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.6.4'
gem install rails 
gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.8.rc3'
```

After that explictly include

```
gem 'nokogiri', '>=1.6.8.rc3'
```

in gemfile

`gem update` works without error
`bundle install` and `bundle update` works too